# Stripe Basic PaymentIntent On Confirm Payment Error

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, payment

I have implemented stripe basic integration in my ios app. I referred this link for integration https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic integration.

When i call  `STPPaymentHandler.shared().confirmPayment(withParams: paymentIntentParams,authenticationContext: paymentContext)`,

Here is my code

```
// Assemble the PaymentIntent parameters
                let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: clientSecret)
                paymentIntentParams.paymentMethodId = paymentResult.paymentMethod?.stripeId
                paymentIntentParams.configure(with: paymentResult)

                // Confirm the PaymentIntent
                STPPaymentHandler.shared().confirmPayment(withParams: paymentIntentParams, authenticationContext: paymentContext) { status, paymentIntent, error in
                    switch status {
                    case .succeeded:
                        // Your backend asynchronously fulfills the customer's order, e.g. via webhook
                        completion(.success, nil)
                    case .failed:
                        completion(.error, error) // Report error
                    case .canceled:
                        completion(.userCancellation, nil) // Customer cancelled
                    @unknown default:
                        completion(.error, nil)
                    }
                }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=50 "The `payment_method` parameter supplied pm_test belongs to the Customer cus_test. Please include the Customer in the `customer` parameter on the PaymentIntent." UserInfo={com.stripe.lib:ErrorMessageKey=The `payment_method` parameter supplied pm_test belongs to the Customer cus_test. Please include the Customer in the `customer` parameter on the PaymentIntent., com.stripe.lib:StripeErrorCodeKey=parameter_missing, com.stripe.lib:StripeErrorTypeKey=invalid_request_error, com.stripe.lib:ErrorParameterKey=paymentMethod, NSLocalizedDescription=The `payment_method` parameter supplied pm_test belongs to the Customer cus_test. Please include the Customer in the `customer` parameter on the PaymentIntent.}.
```

I am getting paymentResult in didCreatePaymentResult like this:

```
<STPPaymentMethod: 0x6000029cfb10; stripeId = pm_stripeID; billingDetails = <STPPaymentMethodBillingDetails: 0x60000174a800; name = (null); phone = (null); email = (null); address = <STPPaymentMethodAddress: 0x6000021e8500; line1 = (null); line2 = (null); city = (null); state = (null); postalCode = (null); country = US>>; card = <STPPaymentMethodCard: 0x6000026c2040; brand = Visa; checks = <STPPaymentMethodCardChecks: 0x600000cad2c0; addressLine1Check: (null); addressPostalCodeCheck: (null); cvcCheck: pass>; country = US; expMonth = 2; expYear = 2025; funding = credit; last4 = 4242; fingerprint = (null); threeDSecureUsage = <STPPaymentMethodThreeDSecureUsage: 0x6000002b86a0; supported: YES>; wallet = (null)>; cardPresent = (null); created = 2019-12-27 11:45:05 +0000; customerId = cus_GR9XK62lIkQYto; ideal = (null); fpx = (null); sepaDebit = (null); liveMode = NO; metadata = {
}; type = card>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt there's something wrong when you setup your server. Check the document and the  `paymentResult` again. It's best you can post your `paymentResult` here so we can see what's missing.

Comment: @Eddie Please check question. i have updated

Comment: Can you share the code you're using on the server to create the PaymentIntent?

Comment: backend code be like this
```$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
            'amount' => 100,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        ]);
        $response['client_secret'] = $intent->client_secret;```

Comment: @Eddie Should i need to pass customer id in this paymentIntent method on server side  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you forgot to pass client in `PaymentIntent`. It is required to pass `clientId` as client is the only thing that binds `ephemeral_key` and `client_secret` together.
Please try following code at server side to generate `client_secret`.

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'customer' => $customerId,
    'amount' => 100,
    'currency' => 'usd',
]);
$response['client_secret'] = $intent->client_secret;
```